# How to: sharepoint workflow with custom list

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007, workflow-foundation

I want to develop a workflow for sharepoint linked to a custom list.
The work flow will be based on a field of the list that represents the state. I have looked for good tutorials on the Internet, but I can't find out one that is ok for me.
My scenario is as follows:

- As a new item of the list is created, the workflow should start.
- In the next steps the user will be asked to fill in a form, submitting the form will make the workflow go on.

How can I make a form "communicate" with the workflow?
Should this be achieved using a Modification form?

Thank you.

Comment: what version of Sharepoint? 2007/2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you even need C# or Visual Studio.

Check out the introduction to [SharePoint Designer and Workflows](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-workflows-HA010100587.aspx).

Your workflow can run on any list - custom or not, doesn't matter. The Workflow can actually run whenever the item it is running on has changed, which is exactly what you want: Whenever someone changes the "state" field, the workflow runs and does whatever it needs to do.

A good example of exactly this is the built in "Three State Workflow" - you only have to activate the feature.

Read up a bit on Workflows to propose a more detailed question. There simply is no answer to your second question whether you should use state machine or sequence workflow - it depends on your use case.

Basically you want this:

1. Run Workflow automatically when item changed
2. Check field "State"
3. Switch field state, if state = "teststate" do this, else do that.

Comment: Hi Moontear, thank you for your reply. I have edited my question, now it should be more clear. The key point is that I can't figure out how to make a form "communicate" with the workflow... Thank you again ;)

Comment: You kind of changed the whole question - maybe you want to post another question? In SPD (Sharepoint Designer) you have so called "Activities" and one of these workflow activities is the "Collect data from user" activity. This activity essentially creates a form for you, you can assign that form to the user, and promote its fields to the list - this way the form fills values in the list.